# How to test that stream emits anything during time interval in unit tests (Flutter)?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter

In my code, the function emits value to the stream after one minute. Let's say it is a timer. I want to do unit testing (not widget testing because the function lives in bloc file). I tried to use fakeAsync as described in doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/quiver.testing.async/FakeAsync-class.html but had no luck. Test fails on timeout.
The tested code:

```
class BarcodeBloc {
  Timer _timer;
  StreamController<bool> _timerFinished;

  BarcodeBloc() {
    _timerFinished = new StreamController();
  }

  Stream<bool> get cameraTimeout => _timerFinished.stream;

  void _tick() {
    _timerFinished.add(true);
  }

  void startTimer() {
    stopTimer();
    print("starting timer");
    _timer = Timer(interval, _tick);
  }

  void stopTimer() {
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
  }
}
```

My code for the test:

```
void main() {

  test("After one minute emits true", () {
    new FakeAsync().run((async) {
       BarcodeBloc barcodeBloc = new BarcodeBloc(preferenceProvider);
       barcodeBloc.startTimer();

       async.elapse(duration);
       expect(barcodeBloc.cameraTimeout, emits(true));
  });
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you still have a problem with this, but I'm doing something very simliar,  using async.elapse to fast forward time on a stream that has a timed delay due to using `debounce()` and all works as expected using current strable v1.12.13+hotfix.7) in std unit tests (*not* widget tests).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. It doesn't seem like `emits` works well with `FakeAsync` and I was having problems using any `await` call within the FakeAsync zone, so what I ended up doing was something like:

```
void main() {
  var streamOutput;

  test("After one minute emits true", () {
    FakeAsync().run((async) {
       BarcodeBloc barcodeBloc = BarcodeBloc(preferenceProvider);
       barcodeBloc.startTimer();
       barcodeBloc.cameraTimeout.listen((value) {
         streamOutput = value;
       });

       async.elapse(duration);
       expect(streamOutput, /* expected value */);
  });
}
```